# How do I read text file and output in Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

i have file: input.txt 
I want to read this file, put values in new output.txt from input.txt.

Servlet.java

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                 "attachment;filename=output.txt");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    ServletContext cntxt = this.getServletContext();
    String fName = "/input.txt";
    InputStream ins = cntxt.getResourceAsStream(fName);
    try {
        if(ins != null){
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        int n = 0;
        String word ="";
        while((word= reader.readLine())!= null)
         {
             n = Integer.parseInt(word);
             out.println(n);
         }
      } finally {
            out.close();
      }
}
```

but output.txt is empty. What's wrong?

Comment: `ins` is probably null. You should use your debugger or add traces to the code to investigate what the problem is, and which lines are actually executed. Do you have an input.txt file at the root of your deployed webapp? What's the point in dynamically serving a static file? Why don't you put the output.txt in your webappa directly?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

`input.txt` should be present in the root directory of your application

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=output.txt");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        ServletContext cntxt = this.getServletContext();
        String fName = "/input.txt";
        InputStream ins = cntxt.getResourceAsStream(fName);
        try {
            if (ins != null) {
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                int n = 0;
                String word = "";
                while ((word = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    n = Integer.parseInt(word);
                    out.println(n);
                }
            }
        }finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code is exactly the same as the OP's code. What's the point of your answer?

Comment: closing braces of your `if` inside `try` is missing in your code

Answer (score 0):

Apache FileUtils, could make it simple

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("file.txt), "UTF-8");

    for (String line : lines) {
        out.println(line);
    }
}
```