# How to print the contents of a file on the Browser

Tags: java, servlets

ReadFile Class

```
public class  ReadFile {

    public void  readFile() throws IOException {

        BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\text.txt"));

        if (is != null) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(is);
            String text;

            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            }
            is.close();


        }
    }
    public static void  main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ReadFile read=new ReadFile();
        read.readFile();
    }
}
```

Servlet class

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    resp.setContentType("text/html");

    ReadFile readfile = new ReadFile();
    readfile.readFile();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem ? It seems you read the file but don't do much with the line... might be the problem...

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java to read text file and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593832/how-do-i-read-text-file-and-output-in-servlet

Comment: @AxelH i have created one read class to read the contents of a file. and i have created a servlet class andi Im calling the read file .. my problem is the how to print the file in the browser?

Comment: if you have read the text file and then you are just to left print out the text into the response.

Comment: @ShafinMahmud but how to do it in the servlet class .. sorry im new to java and need to knw . please help me

Answer (score 0):

The class ReadFile needs to receive a PrintWriter parameter, `resp.getWriter()`.
The character encoding was not handled both on reading the file, as on presenting it in the browser. Here I elected for both UTF-8.

For the file it might be `Charset.forName("Windows-1252")` or such.

As the java Files class has everything that ReadFile could do, I used that.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    Path path = Paths.get("D:\\text.txt");
    Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        .forEach(out::println));
}
```

Or using HTML formatting:

```
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    out.println("<html><head>");
    out.println("<meta charset='UTF-8'>");
    out.println("<title>The text<title>");
    out.println("</head><body><pre>");
    Path path = Paths.get("D:\\text.txt");
    Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        .forEach(line -> {
             line = line.replace("&", "&amp;")
                 .replace("<", "&lt;")
                 .replace(">", "&gt;");
             out.printl(line);
        });
    out.println("</pre></body></html>");
```

---

***With using a ReadFile class:***

```
public class  ReadFile {

    public void  readFile(PrintWriter out) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("D:\\text.txt");
        Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .forEach(out::println));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {   
        ReadFile read = new ReadFile();
        read.readFile(new PrintWriter(System.out));
    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    ReadFile read = new ReadFile();
    read.readFile(System.out);
}
```

Comment: but the file path should be given only in ReadFileClass. In servelt Class we should just call the ReadFile class

Comment: I tried this above code even then the contents of a file didn't get displayed on the browser